# Selenium side runner not working, opens jest.js

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

like the title says; when I'm running the `selenium-side-runner C:\Selenium\*.side`  command it opens jest.js, located in \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-side-runner\node_modules\jest\bin, instead of executing my tests located in the folder.

[image]

I really can't find any information about this happening to other people.
The versions of my installed packages:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm really stock on this one...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look like it's a bug of `version 4.0.0-alpha.46`. I'm able to run it after downgrade the selenium-side-runner to `3.17.0`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).